# How to run many triggers with LOCK without discarding one?

Tags: google-apps-script, locking, google-calendar-api

I am using a google calendar trigger which fires every time an event changes.

Within the trigger I execute some logic which should not run in parallel by other triggers so this code block should run sequentiel (one trigger by the other).
Here is some pseudo code to explain it:

```
// BEGIN - start lock here

var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
try {
   lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and 
lock to stop and then proceed
 } catch (e) {
   Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds.');
 }
// Start CODE BLOCK WHICH SHOULD NEVER RUN PARALLEL BY OTHER TRIGGERS

doSomeBackendCalls();
doSomeOtherStuff();
// END CODEBLOCK


lock.releaseLock();

// END - end lock here

return;
```

So if I understood the Lock Service correctly this should work as intended. When for example 2 Trigger run at the same time one is locking while the other one is waiting until the lock is released right?

My problem is that this does not scale very good. When the code block for example takes 2 seconds to run and 30 Triggers run within one seconds, not all Triggers will run the code block.

So my question is how to solve this?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833498/14606045) for a similar issue.

Comment: this actually does not answer my question at all. The problem I wanted to describe was that if there are too many triggers the execution time could exceed the timeout. How can I handle this?